# Print dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

File1 only has 1 column: name/
File2 has 3 columns: name, num1, num2

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
data_list1 = data_to_match['Name1']

data2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
data_list2  = data_master['Name2']


recode = {}
for name in data_list1:
    best_match = process.extractOne(name, data_list2)
    if best_match[1] < 100:
        print(name, best_match, data_list2.num1, data_list2.num2)
    recode[name] = best_match[0]
```

How do I print out the num1, num2 in the print statement?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `fuzzywuzzy` (`process.extractOne`) does not take a `pandas.Series`, you need to call it with a list.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar a fuzzywuzzy method

Comment: @user3471881 how do I call the list?

Comment: nobody can help?

Comment: Can you post sample data of File and FIle 2